# Populating textarea box from multiple dropdowns/checkboxes/textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these 3 drop-down menus, multiple check boxes and textboxes that I need to populate with alternative values in a textarea box, what I need to do is show all in order, separated by a comma like this...

4300013076, 10, 563, 2, 6532

Basically what happening it's replacing the figure with whatever was selected last. I cant even put together how to add in check-boxes and textboxes I'm really new at this and could use some help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#element_45').change(function() {
    var myValue = $(this).val();
    switch (myValue) {
    case '6':
        $('textarea[id="element_247"]').val('4300013076');
        break;
    case '12':
        $('textarea[id="element_247"]').val('4300013077');
        break;
    case '13':
        $('textarea[id="element_247"]').val('4300013078');
        break;
    case '14':
        $('textarea[id="element_247"]').val('4300013492');
        break;
    }
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#element_46').change(function() {
    var myValue = $(this).val();
    switch (myValue) {
    case '20':
        $('textarea[id="element_247"]').val('10');
        break;
    case '21':
        $('textarea[id="element_247"]').val('14');
        break;
    case '22':
        $('textarea[id="element_247"]').val('17');
        break;
    case '23':
        $('textarea[id="element_247"]').val('18');
        break;
    }
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#element_47').change(function() {
    var myValue = $(this).val();
    switch (myValue) {
    case '30':
        $('textarea[id="element_247"]').val('561');
        break;
    case '31':
        $('textarea[id="element_247"]').val('562');
        break;
    case '32':
        $('textarea[id="element_247"]').val('563');
        break;
    case '33':
        $('textarea[id="element_247"]').val('564');
        break;
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="element_45">
<option value="" >None</option>
<option value="6">text1</option>
<option value="12">text2</option>
<option value="13">text3</option>
<option value="14">text4</option>
</select>
<select id="element_46">
<option value="" >None</option>
<option value="20">text5</option>
<option value="21">text6</option>
<option value="22">text7</option>
<option value="23">text8</option>
</select>
<select id="element_47">
<option value="" >None</option>
<option value="30">text9</option>
<option value="31">text10</option>
<option value="32">text11</option>
<option value="33">text12</option>
</select>
<input id="element_490" name="element_490" class="element text medium" value=""/>
<input id="element_227_1"  name="element_227_1" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1"  />
<label class="choice" for="element_227_1">Yes</label>
<textarea id="element_247"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a translation object and listen to all select box changes by selecting the `select`. Then with each change, read all select boxes, and collect the values into an array. That way you can use `Array#join` which lets you define the "glue".

I use `Array#reduce` to generate the collection value array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // collect selectboxes - respecting the order
  const selectBoxes = [
    $( '#element_45' ),
    $( '#element_46' ),
    $( '#element_47' ),
  ];
  const textbox = $( 'textarea#element_247' );
  
  // translate values
  const translateValues = {
    // possible #element_45 values
    '45': {
      '6': '4300013076',
      '12': '4300013077',
      '13': '4300013078',
      '14': '4300013492',
    },
    // possible #element_46 values
    '46': {
      '20': '10',
      '21': '14',
      '22': '17',
      '23': '18',
    },
    // possible #element_47 values
    '47': {
      '30': '561',
      '31': '562',
      '32': '563',
      '33': '564',
    },
  };

  // Listen to all select changes
  $( 'select' ).change( function() {
    const values = selectBoxes.reduce( ( collectedValues, box ) => {
      // Convert value to number
      const val = box.val();
      
      // Skip empty boxes
      if ( val == 0 ) {
        return collectedValues;
      }
      
      // Get id of box
      const id = box.attr( 'id' ).split( '_' )[ 1 ];

      // Get value and add to collection
      const t = translateValues[ id ][ val ];
      // Only add value, when it is defined in our object
      if ( t ) {
        collectedValues.push( t );
      }
      
      return collectedValues;
    }, [] );
    
    // Set textarea value
    textbox.val( values.join( ', ' ) );
  } );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="element_45">
    <option value="" >None</option>
    <option value="6">text1</option>
    <option value="12">text2</option>
    <option value="13">text3</option>
    <option value="14">text4</option>
</select>
<select id="element_46">
    <option value="" >None</option>
    <option value="20">text5</option>
    <option value="21">text6</option>
    <option value="22">text7</option>
    <option value="23">text8</option>
</select>
<select id="element_47">
    <option value="" >None</option>
    <option value="30">text9</option>
    <option value="31">text10</option>
    <option value="32">text11</option>
    <option value="33">text12</option>
</select>
<textarea id="element_247"></textarea>
```

Comment: You could remove the `+` from `+box.val();` and `+box.attr` and convert all translations to a string by wrapping them in quotes.

Comment: Wow! This looks like the easiest solution, quite remarkable actually! Would be easy to add additional drop downs or remove some if it nor needed. Very cool! Only thing I see is if I have values that have spaces or additional commas it doesn't work. `    // possible #element_45 values
    45: {
      6: 4300013076 2134,
      12: 4300013077 6521,
      13: 4300013078 5554,
      14: 4300013492 1324,
    },
`

Comment: I updated my answer. Now you should be able to add spaces.

Comment: You nailed it!! Thanks SOOOO much!

Comment: I'm not trying to be greedy, but is there a way to include check boxes and textboxes into this script? So, if a checkbox is clicked, it could have a value like the drop-down boxes in this script and what ever is typed in the input textbox it copies whatever is typed into that box? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I've updated this thread with additional information and some new HTML hoping that you could see what I trying to accomplish and update your brilliant script to included a few more options. Thanks for your consideration. @lumio

Comment: Hey @agdm619... I don't want to be rude but I think I gave you enough inspiration to get you started ;) SO is not here to get free code snippets. What you are trying to do is possible and you could easily get it done with some research. All you need is another check for an input value when generating your textbox value

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the information you have given it has help me learn and get better. All the best to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential solution that stores the desired data in a `data-val` attribute for each `select` object, and then calls an update function that grabs all existing `data-val` attributes, puts them into an array, and joins them in the textbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#element_45').change(function() {
      var myValue = $(this).val();
      switch (myValue) {
      case '6':
          $(this).attr('data-val','4300013076');
          break;
      case '12':
          $(this).attr('data-val','4300013077');
          break;
      case '13':
          $(this).attr('data-val','4300013078');
          break;
      case '14':
          $(this).attr('data-val','4300013492');
          break;
      }
      update();
  });

  $('#element_46').change(function() {
      var myValue = $(this).val();
      switch (myValue) {
      case '20':
          $(this).attr('data-val', '10');
          break;
      case '21':
          $(this).attr('data-val', '14');
          break;
      case '22':
          $(this).attr('data-val', '17');
          break;
      case '23':
          $(this).attr('data-val', '18');
          break;
      }
      update();
  });

  $('#element_47').change(function() {
      var myValue = $(this).val();
      switch (myValue) {
      case '30':
          $(this).attr('data-val', '561');
          break;
      case '31':
          $(this).attr('data-val', '562');
          break;
      case '32':
          $(this).attr('data-val', '563');
          break;
      case '33':
          $(this).attr('data-val', '564');
          break;
      }
      update();
  });

  function update() {
      var allSelects = [];
      $('select').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('data-val'))
          allSelects.push($(this).attr('data-val'));
      })
      $('textarea[id="element_247"]').val(allSelects.join(', '));
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="element_45">
    <option value="" >None</option>
    <option value="6">text1</option>
    <option value="12">text2</option>
    <option value="13">text3</option>
    <option value="14">text4</option>
</select> 
<select id="element_46">
    <option value="" >None</option>
    <option value="20">text5</option>
    <option value="21">text6</option>
    <option value="22">text7</option>
    <option value="23">text8</option>
</select>
<select id="element_47">
    <option value="" >None</option>
    <option value="30">text9</option>
    <option value="31">text10</option>
    <option value="32">text11</option>
    <option value="33">text12</option>
</select> 
<textarea id="element_247"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution, but using string literals:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {   
    var value45 = '', value46 = '', value47 = '';
    var textArea = $('textarea[id="element_247"]');
  
    $('#element_45').change(function () {
        var myValue = $(this).val();
        switch (myValue) {
          case '6':
              value45 = '4300013076';
              break;
          case '12':
              value45 = '4300013077';
              break;
          case '13':
              value45 = '4300013078';
              break;
          case '14':
              value45 = '4300013492';
              break;
        }
       textArea.val(`${value45}, ${value46}, ${value47}`);
    });

    $('#element_46').change(function () {
        var myValue = $(this).val();
      
        switch (myValue) {
          case '20':
              value46 = '10';
              break;
          case '21':
              value46 = '14';
              break;
          case '22':
              value46 = '17';
              break;
          case '23':
              value46 = '18';
              break;
        }
      

       textArea.val(`${value45}, ${value46}, ${value47}`);
    });

    $('#element_47').change(function () {
        var myValue = $(this).val();
      
        switch (myValue) {
          case '30':
              value47 = '561';
              break;
          case '31':
              value47 = '562';
              break;
          case '32':
              value47 = '563';
              break;
          case '33':
              value47 = '564';
              break;
        }
      
       textArea.val(`${value45}, ${value46}, ${value47}`);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="element_45">
    <option value="" >None</option>
    <option value="6">text1</option>
    <option value="12">text2</option>
    <option value="13">text3</option>
    <option value="14">text4</option>
</select> 
<select id="element_46">
    <option value="" >None</option>
    <option value="20">text5</option>
    <option value="21">text6</option>
    <option value="22">text7</option>
    <option value="23">text8</option>
</select>
<select id="element_47">
    <option value="" >None</option>
    <option value="30">text9</option>
    <option value="31">text10</option>
    <option value="32">text11</option>
    <option value="33">text12</option>
</select> 
<textarea id="element_247"></textarea>
```